# Docker can't remove volume symlinked to external drive

Tags: docker, cifs

I have Docker installed on a machine, and I'd like to relocate it's volumes to a CIFS share. I created the share and mounted it at `/media/nas/docker-data`. I then moved my `/var/lib/docker/volumes` onto it, and then replaced that folder with a symlink to `/media/nas/docker-data/volumes`.

However, Docker doesn't seem happy about this situation, and when I try to `docker volume rm ...` an old volume, I get this:

```
Error response from daemon: remove d9255a78b8f12f7b6b5da9e2b291ea445c1984ba263c73452fabb3bbb3574ed1: Unable to remove a directory outside of the local volume root /var/lib/docker: /media/nas/docker-data/volumes/d9255a78b8f12f7b6b5da9e2b291ea445c1984ba263c73452fabb3bbb3574ed1/_data
```

Is there some sort of whitelist I can use to let Docker know it's okay to manage these files?